# InputStream closed by ImageIO

Tags: java, inputstream, ioexception, javax.imageio

I ran into a very weird problem with ImageIO.

A couple of object in my java program have an Image. I load these images via my ImageManager with the static method load.

```
public static Image load(String path){
    Image img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(ImageManager.class.getResource(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(img == null){
        System.out.println("Image: '" + path + "' not found!");
    }

    return img;
}
```

Whenever i load the (static) background image or load an image in my render method there is no problem.

Also when loading images into static variables in my Card class there is no problem. But as soon as i load images dynamically from my Card constructor an Exception is thrown saying the stream is closed.

```
java.io.IOException: closed
Image: '/textures/cards/back.png' not found!
at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.checkClosed(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:110)
at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.close(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:857)
at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageInputStream.close(FileCacheImageInputStream.java:250)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1451)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)
at visual.gfx.ImageManager.load(ImageManager.java:15)
at visual.Card.<init>(Card.java:49)
at visual.WorldController.render(WorldController.java:98)
at visual.WorldController.run(WorldController.java:116)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So to be clear:
This:

```
public class Card{
    public static Image BACK = ImageManager.load("/textures/cards/back.png");
}
```

works just fine.

and This:

```
public class Card{
    private Image image;

    public Card(){
        image = ImageManager.load("/textures/cards/back.png");
    }
}
```

Results into an IOException.

**Can someone tell me why this is happening and how i can do things differently?**

**Edit:**

I am not sure how or why this exception occured, but i managed to temporarily fix it.

The structure of my program was like this:

```
public void run(){
    init();
        while(running){
            update();
            render();
        }
    finish();
}
```

I planned to load all images and create all instances from the init method.
But just to test my load method i quickly created an instance of `Card`.

But when i tried to load the Image it threw an exception. Loading the Image from the `init()` method solved my issue.

Can anyone tell me why this makes such a difference.

btw this is my render method.

```
public void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        bs = getBufferStrategy();
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);

    // render actual game

    game.render(g);

    // ------------------

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

- I did add a res folder to the project such that the images are located: ~/res/textures/cards/back.png

Comment: `Image: '/textures/cards/blue1.png' not found!` `("/textures/cards/back.png");` blue1.png != back.png please explain

Comment: Is `/textures/cards/back.png` in your classpath? You are not loading files but instead classpath resources.

Comment: @ControlAltDelete these are two textures that i use. I know they are not the same but it results in the same error

Comment: Yes i did add a res folder to my class path. The image is located: ~/res/textures/cards/back.png

Comment: Are you on Windows, Linux, other? Is the case of your path correct?

Comment: I just tried (by recreating the code you didn't post), and for me it works the same either way. So, either there's something about your environment that you haven't told us about, or a typo of some sort, or perhaps a file access issue. For better help, create a fully working [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exposes the problem, and make sure you include the relevant environment info (OS, JVM version etc).

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc for ImageIO.read(URL) is a bit vague, but it seems it's caching the input stream internally based on the URL, and it's not obvious how it behaves in the multi-threaded environment.

I'd give a shot to ImageIO.read(InputStream) instead if I were you.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Slava Imeshev

Comment: `ImageIO` (or, the `ImageInputStream` implementations, really) caches the content of *any* input stream, to be able to seek backwards, regardless of input. This caching is *per stream* (not per URL) and is completely thread-safe (from `ImageIO.read(...)`'s point of view). However, using the `ImageIO.read(InputStream)` method as you suggests, might help find the cause of the exception (which most likely is that the resource doesn't exist, or isn't readable).